# How to check or log messages if we use Autosar PDUR

Tags: analysis, autosar, automotive

We use Autosar to implement automotive gateway, and the PDUR module can be configured to route message from one interface to other protocol interfaces.
My question is if we want to do message check, analysis or logging, how could we know what message routed by PDUR? should I configure all the message transfer to SW-C application layer for analysis or is there any other method to do above deep message inspection feature.

Thanks
Jack

Answer (score 0):

When I hear analysis and logging, I already get bad headache, because of features, that are put into ECUs but rather should be tested with proper stress tests from outside, e.g. PDUs on network A is seen on network B after whatever milliseconds. For such logging, you usually need a EEPROM or FLASH with a certain P/E cycles, which will just add to the price of the ECU without much benefit. And it also impacts your ECUs performance.

Regarding PduR message based routing, you should be very careful because:

- Depending on CanRxProcessing, the handling of the PduR routing is handled on Interrupt level, so your "deep message checks" increase your ISR runtime/locktime!
- Certain features in Can and CanIf (and also other bus specific network components) might already discard received messages, so PduR might not even be informed about it (e.g. static DLC check, message in BasicCAN HRH is blocked by SW filtering)
- Some messages might not be routed by PduR directly, like signal based routing is actually handled in Com not in PduR, maybe protocols are routed by protocol specific modules and not by PduR
- CanTp can have multiple addressing formats, where the N_TA is in the first data byte. Here it is tricky to handle multiple connections, if you think about certina N_TAs not being routed
- Not sure about SecOC, is the gateway only routing authenticated messages?
- Some routed messages could be disabled/enabled on the fly (Routing path groups)

Routed messages from network to network usually have a so called routing relationships (Routing paths). In the end, there should be a table somehow, but this depends also on your implementation, e.g. Vector, ETAS, Elektrobit, ...

So, my opinion is, that deep message check, I don't see what you would gain at all here, in the ECU. I would rather prefer a proper Stress Test with certain tooling from the outside.